# Simplification of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Can the expression $(5\vec{u} \times \vec{v})\cdot(2 \vec{u}-7\vec{v})$ be simplified? 
$\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$ are not necessarily part of any orthogonal system.
I don't really know how to use any kind of distributive property to go any further... The "$\cdot$" is dot product and "$\times$" is cross product. Isn't this just equal to $0$??

Comment: What makes you think it is 0?

Comment: $(5\vec{u} \times \vec{v}))$ is orthogonal to the what you're dotting it with, right?

Comment: The cross product is orthogonal to each of its factors as well as any linear combinations of them

Comment: ^ so you mean to say its zero right?

Answer (score 1):

$(\vec x \times \vec y)\cdot \vec x=0$, for any vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, because the cross-product of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ is perpendicular to $\vec x$. Now distribute the $(5\vec u\times\vec v)$.

Comment: I'm confused about how to distribute in this context, can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: $(5\vec u\times\vec v)\cdot(2\vec u - 7\vec v) = 2 (5\vec u\times\vec v)\cdot \vec u - 7 (5\vec u\times\vec v)\cdot \vec v$. The dot product $\cdot$ is distributive.

Answer (score 0):

If given no knowledge of what $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are equal to, then $$(5\vec{u} \times \vec{v})\cdot(2 \vec{u}-7\vec{v}) $$ is already simplified as far as possible.

Comment: I think the answer is $0$

Comment: @djax Why is that?

Comment: (5u×v)) is orthogonal to the what you're dotting it with, right?

Comment: visiualize it..